# AutoMapper with dynamic destination property

Tags: c#, automapper

We are attempting to create a tool that allows users to map properties between classes and database values.

I'd like to use AutoMapper to map from the `DataRow` to a class, so long as we manually create the mapping for each property.  For example

```
 cfg.CreateMap<DataRow, SupplierInventory>()
  .ForMember(m => m.Id,
      s => s.MapFrom(r =>
          r[
              fields.FirstOrDefault(c =>
              c.DestinationTable == nameof(SupplierInventory) &&
              c.DestinationField == nameof(SupplierInventory.Id)).SourceField]))
  .ForMember(m => m.Description,
      s => s.MapFrom(r =>
           r[
              fields.FirstOrDefault(c =>
                  c.DestinationTable == nameof(SupplierInventory) &&
                  c.DestinationField == nameof(SupplierInventory.Description)).SourceField]))
.ForMember(m => m.Size,
    s => s.MapFrom(r =>
        r[
             fields.FirstOrDefault(c =>
             c.DestinationTable == nameof(SupplierInventory) &&
             c.DestinationField == nameof(SupplierInventory.Size)).SourceField]));
```

This will SUCCESSFULLY map from a DataRow (r) on the field selected by fields.FirstOrDefault.

To make it more generic, I'd like to loop through each property and add the property based on the property name.

```
IMappingExpression<DataRow, SupplierInventory> map = new MappingExpression<DataRow, SupplierInventory>(MemberList.None);
var props = typeof(SupplierInventory).GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    map.ForMember(p => p.Id, s => s.MapFrom(r =>
      r[
         fields.FirstOrDefault(c =>
           c.DestinationTable == nameof(SupplierInventory) &&
           c.DestinationField == prop.Name).SourceField]));
}
```

However, I can't seem to set the **DESTINATION** dynamically, and have to use

```
p => p.Property,
```

I can't do

```
p => p.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
```

Is this a possible feat in AutoMapper?  Thanks

Comment: With ForAllMembers you have access to the destination member.

Comment: See also [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/f23b61dd76ed5a40fb6d3926fb5d4201).